# Display content of JSON data page with SSL

Tags: php, json, ssl, curl

I have a SSL page with multi-data of JSON.

I would like to use get_content and decode each data as a range for my JSON data.

I am using this code:

```
$url = 'https://www.myurl.....';
$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

foreach($data as $page) {
     if (strstr($page['key'],'v2-')){ 
        echo "<section>";
        echo $page['content'];
        echo "</section>";
    }
}
```

The problem is, I am getting this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 86

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 86

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.myurl.....): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 86

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 89
```

I tried to alter my code to this:

```
function getSSLPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

echo getSSLPage("https://www.myurl.....");
```

I also tried:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Neither gave any good results.

next i do :

```
<?php

        $streamContextOptions=array(
            "ssl"=>array(
                "verify_peer"=>false,
                "verify_peer_name"=>false,
            ),
        );

        $url = "https://www.myurl...";
        $jsonData = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($streamContextOptions));
        $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
        $value = "v2-";

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                echo "<section>";
                echo $data['content'];
                echo "</section>";

        }
?>
```

and i have :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 41

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 41

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.myurl...): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 41

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php on line 45
```

new step :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.myurl');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    $value = "v2-";

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            echo "<section>";
            echo $data['content'];
            echo "</section>";

    }
```

with answer :

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/vivreune/www/metairie-paulhac/bl-themes/Metairie-V2/php/home.php</b> on line <b>55</b>
```

step of 12 septembre 2016 :
my htaccess :

```
# Enable rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^muyrl\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.myurl.fr/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15811200" env=HTTPS


  $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.metairie-paulhac.fr/api/show/page/accueil');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){ echo 'Curl error: <br/>' . curl_error($ch); };
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

do :

```
    Curl error: 
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Comment: Try also setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false in addition to your other options.

Comment: where did i do that ?, on wich try

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`

Comment: Also, what version of SSL are you using? `file_get_contents()` doesn't currently support SSL3 which means you'll have to use the cURL implementation.

Comment: Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0

Comment: It's a bug in PHP, SSL3 doesn't work with file_get_contents().

Comment: ok, then what i can do ?? xD

Comment: Use cURL with the option I specified, along with your previous options like CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER set to false and CURLOPT_SSLVERSION set to 3.

Comment: i've update my post, i have an error into the foreach()

Comment: That's because you're not using it correctly.

Comment: i'm so sorry, but i'm a little tired and i don't see where is the bad request.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/N3NU8u4r

Comment: It says `SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number` which means you have the incorrect SSL version set. Your options for CURLOPT_SSLVERSION are CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT (0), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (1), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 (2), CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 (3), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5) or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6).

Comment: ok have found with :    curl_setopt($ch, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3, 3);

Comment: new error : Curl error: couldn't connect to hostArray

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3, 3);` is not correct because `CURL_SSLVERSION_SSv3` is not a valid option. It's a macro for a value. So, ***if*** you want to use SSLv3 then you would say `curl_setopt($ch, CURL_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3);`. However, you should only do so if that's the version you're using.

Comment: i don't found any available version :/

Comment: Try all of them then, starting with 6 then 5, 4, 3, etc.

Comment: for info my curl version is 7.21.0

Comment: for my test, all version over v3 write the same error but v2 or v1 make a long time request and (after 2min) gateway error, to much time.

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.

Comment: an other solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` to see if it gives you any more information.

Comment: hi again, i do 1 new test, explain in my original post + verbose

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate might not be verified by a CA. Try the following and see if it works.

```
$streamContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

$url = "https://www.example.com/somepage";
$jsonData = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($streamContextOptions));
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

By the way, you could use `foreach($data as $key => $value)` which gives you back the key and value instead of checking with the `strstr()` method every time.

Comment: my result of your answer :

Comment: strstr() is to don't display some pages.

Comment: I know, so check $key instead of using strstr().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your data structure looks, so I'm going to use your previous version of the foreach method. At the very least, using cURL as I recommended in the comments of your question seems to have gotten rid of the other error. Therefore, try the following.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.myurl');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($data as $page) {
    if (strstr($page['key'],'v2-')){ 
        echo "<section>";
        echo $page['content'];
        echo "</section>";
    }
}
```

Comment: same : <b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/vivreune/www/metairie/home.php</b> on line <b>53</b><br />

Comment: i will give you my datasource on your tweeter

Comment: That means that `$data` is not as you would expect. In fact, `$result` will either be True or False in this case because `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is not set to true. Sorry for misleading you, but I did so in order for you to understand curl_exec(). According to documentation, `curl_exec()` returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Comment: ok ... so, i'ts my $data who be without any result if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is not set or set with false and with data if he is set . sorry, i'm french and i try to all understanding

Comment: Yes, `$data` will be a boolean if `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is not set to True.

Comment: so when i can collect the result of this curl ?

Comment: Try to `echo $result` onto the page and see what it returns. That should help you understand what you need to do next.

Comment: if i do :     $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.myurl');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;

i have nothing

Comment: Try to check for errors. `if(curl_errno($ch)){ echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); } print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));`

Answer (score 0):

so, finally i found it, it was so easy ...

```
$url = 'http://www.myurl:443/myapipages';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);
    foreach($data as $page) {
        if (strstr($page['key'],'v2-')){ 
            echo "<section>";
            echo $page['content'];
            echo "</section>";
        }
    }
```